# Can't navigate to another component -> error:Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

On my `react native` app I have a `header` and it consists of:

```
export default class foto extends Component {
.
.
.
.
static navigationOptions = {
        headerTitle: <Titulo/>,
        headerTitleStyle: {
            color: 'white',
        },
        headerRight: <MenuIcon/>,
        headerLeft: <HomeIcon/>,
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#d87c3a'
        }
};

}
```

And I want, when I press on the `headerRight` to navigate to a component, the problem is that when I try I get an error saying: `Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined`

The `<MenuIcon/>` is outside of the `default class foto` but in the same file

MenuIcon code:

```
class MenuIcon extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <TouchableOpacity style={{marginRight:10}}>
                <Icon name={'md-menu'} size={26} color='white'
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('menu')}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
}
```

My StackNavigator on `App.js`:

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  login2: {
    screen: Login2
  },
  foto: {
    screen: Foto
  },
  menu: {
    screen: Menu
  }
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'login2',
});




export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

My Imports:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View, ImageBackground, Image, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, TouchableHighlight, Button } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
```

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: not a pro with reactr but seing 'this' in any kind of javascript is never a good idea oO

Comment: @jonathanHeindl I'm just doing like the documentation on [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html) says

Comment: what are your imports ?

Comment: I already added to my question

Comment: only difference i noticed is that thers a view element around it in the example maybe thats important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass navigation to your `<MenuIcon/>` so your navigation would be something like the following:

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  login2: {
    screen: Login2
  },
  foto: {
    screen: Foto,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerTitle: <Titulo/>,
    headerTitleStyle: {
        color: 'white',
    },
    headerRight: <MenuIcon navigation={navigation}/>,
    headerLeft: <HomeIcon/>,
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#d87c3a'
    }
     })
  },
  menu: {
    screen: Menu
  }
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'login2',
});


export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

This should allow you to navigate from MenuIcon component
Note that you don't need the navigation options in the Foto class, and don't forget to import both MenuIcon and HomeIcon to the stack navigator page

Hopefully this will fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you! It solved my problem. One last question, for all my screens that have a header should I proceed like in this one?

Comment: Sure, You can follow this approach